# STM32F4-Discovery board RTC

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, stm32f4-discovery

RTC Crystal place is exposed on the STM32F4-Discovery board. So which kind of 32.768 KHz SMD Crystals is proper for that place? Could you give a part number or a link to buy?

[image]

Comment: The [User Guide for your board](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/70/fe/4a/3f/e7/e1/4f/7d/DM00039084.pdf/files/DM00039084.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00039084.pdf) recommends a [MC306-G-06Q-32.768](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/epson/MC-306-32.768K-E3-ROHS/SER2417CT-ND/1532560). Don't forget to also fit R21, R22, C16 & C27 too.

Comment: The datasheet for that board or the datasheet for the CPU should have all those details. It is more for a date/time clock than a RTC, which can be done by using a timer. A RTC is not always 1HZ. It can be 1KHZ/1MHZ/1GHZ.

Comment: @brhans. You could post that comment as a valid answer.

Comment: @brhans I agree with Sparky.  I use that board and your comment added to my knowledge base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [User Guide for your board](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/70/fe/4a/3f/e7/e1/4f/7d/DM00039084.pdf/files/DM00039084.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00039084.pdf) recommends a [MC306-G-06Q-32.768](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/epson/MC-306-32.768K-E3-ROHS/SER2417CT-ND/1532560).
I referred to the schematic on page 28:
[image]
Don't forget to also fit R21, R22, C16 & C27 too.

If you choose a different crystal to use, make sure you check that crystal's datasheet for the appropriate capacitance values to use for C16 & C27.